# lightbox image gallery for a single thumbnail

Tags: gallery, lightbox

All "lightbox scripts" have the image gallery option which are built like this:

```
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="image_big_1.jpg"><img src="image_small_1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="image_big_2.jpg"><img src="image_small_2.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Take for example the [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/home) plugin and look at the image galleries, there are 3 thumbnails for those 3 images in the gallery, my question is how to add those 3 images in the lightbox in only one thumbnail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only put one img tag.  So for all but the first a href you have nothing in-between.

```
<a href.......><img src...><\a>
<a href.......><\a>
<a href.......><\a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking at this too...  So, this seems to be the best solution.